# which one is correct to use in my sentence? (that/ - / in which)

Tags: word-usage

> the first step is to find topic ( **that**/ **in which**/ **-** ) you know enough about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but there are actually several errors in your sentence.

A suggested correction

> The first step is to find **a** topic [that] you know enough about.

Note that the indefinite article "a" is not optional here. Also you shouldn't use "it" at the end of your sentence since "that" already refers to the "topic".  You can also omit "that" since it's already implied by the context.  Also, "in which" doesn't work here at all.

If you are trying to avoid using a preposition at the end of your sentence because a teacher told you that this is a rule in English (it's not actually a rule), then you could say "a topic about which you know enough". But don't use this in everyday speech. It's overly formal, and unnatural.